# String as a parameter (C++)

Tags: c++, string, parameters, int, concatenation

Is this example code valid?

```
std::string x ="There are";
int butterflies = 5;
//the following function expects a string passed as a parameter
number(x + butterflies + "butterflies");
```

The main question here is whether I could just pass my integer as part of the string using the + operator. But if there are any other errors there please let me know :)

Comment: `Is this example code valid?` -- What does your compiler tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A safe way to convert your integers to strings would be an excerpt as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string intToString(int x)
{
  std::string ret;
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << x;
  ss >> ret;
  return ret;
}
```

Your current example will not work for reasons mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

C++ doesn't do automatic conversion to strings like that. You need to create a stringstream or use something like boost lexical cast.

Answer (score 2):

You can use stringstream for this purpose like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream st;
    string str;

    st << 1 << " " << 2 << " " << "And this is string" << endl;
    str = st.str();

    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't work. C++ it no a typeless language. So it can't automatically cast integer to string. Use something like strtol, stringstream, etc.

Answer (score 1):

More C than C++, but `sprintf` (which is like `printf`, but puts the result in a string) would be useful here.